# how to make a numbers and the letter e only text box?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a text box that I enter big numbers in and use the letter e to make them look shorter also I don't want to be able to insert letters in it, I have tried a big if and a lot of if elses but it didn't work and I deleted them sorry I can't provide any code, thank you in advance.

```
<input type="text">
```

this is a basic text box, I believe I need javascript to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

change the value of your type from "text" to "number"